# Jquery animation movement not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Hello i have this code

```
<img id="ikona1" src="images/user.png" alt="Users Cloud"/>
```

and i have this code at jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button65").click(function() {
    $("#ikona3").animate({left: "+=300px"},200);
});});
```

when i press the button it doesn't move

**BUT**

if i change the code to `({width: "120px"},200);` it works...

i don't understand why it doesn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I have set up an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtaG3/) where it works.
Don't forget to set a positioning on the image through CSS:

```
#ikona1 {position: absolute;} /* relative or fixed would also work */
```

Answer (score 0):

You have html element with id ikona1, but selecting element with id ikona3 with jquery.
Maybe you should do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button65").click(function(e) {
        $("#ikona1").animate({left: "+=300px"},200);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Also check if your element has `position:absolute;` in css.